# SOA and varying VDS

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, saturation, power-dissipation, safe-operating-area

In a hot-swap application the FET spends some time in the linear region/Saturation region before it moves into the ohmic region.

Here is a snippet of the turn on waveform seen for a FET:
Yellow is battery voltage (VD).
Green is output (VS).
Blue is inrush current on turn on.

[image]

As can be seen the VDS varies in the linear region as the output reaches the battery voltage.

Here is the SOA for the FET used in this application:

[image]

How do i determine the SOA point or margin? The time spent in linear region is ~2.5ms But during this time VDS varies.

The total energy dissipated is in this area in red right (for linear region)?:
Or do we consider the worst case VDS (51.4V), max current (27.3A) and time in linear ~2.5ms and use this to set a point on the SOA curve?

[image]

Comment: You can plot your VDS and Id from your scope photo on the SOA curve, then see for what time period you exceed any of the single-pulse lines.  Keep in mind that the SOA curves are typical, not guaranteed,  and for 25C.  So apply a reasonable derating factor.  Also keep in mind that planar FETs tend to do much better than trench FETs in hot-swap applications.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Planar FETs tend to have pretty bad RDSon and this is a high continuous current application. I couldn't find a Trench FET that  was comfortably in the SOA region. By the sounds of it i should planar FETs which are comfortably in the SOA region and then parallel them up to distribute current?

Comment: Trench FETs suffer from the Spirito effect (you can Google it) so for best reliability paralleling planar FETs (if done correctly, e.g. individual gate resistors, careful layout) is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst reading more on hotswap design i came across the answer I was lookign for and so posting it here if it's ever useful to anybody else.

TI covers this in the following app note: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva673a/slva673a.pdf?ts=1663233798502&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

[image]